# how to set send/receive timeout on czmq?

Tags: c, zeromq

I want to know how can I set timeout on `zstr_send()` and `zstr_recv()` in czmq library.

I know that this can be done with `zmq_setsockopt (requester, ZMQ_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout))` in `libzmq`, but not in `czmq`

What is the syntax for `libczmq`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep! find it...

`zsock_set_rcvtimeo()` and `zsock_set_sndtimeo()` are the answers for setting timouts.

czmq does not have good docs for its good APIs! :|

There are lots of APIs in [`zsock_option()`](http://czmq.zeromq.org/3-0:zsock-option) which has no documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select :

```
int64_t start; 
struct timeval tv;
fd_set fds;
int fd,rc;
tv.tv_sec = 1; // timeout in seconds
tv.tv_usec = 0;
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(fd, &fds);

start = zclock_time ();
zstr_send (client, "hello");
rc = select(fd + 1, &fds, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, &tv);
if (rc == 0) {
// timeoout expired 
}
if (rc == -1) {
// erreur select 
}
// message recieved  before timeout
printf (" message recieved s/second\n",  (1000 * 10000) / (int) (zclock_time () - start));
```

Comment: I don't want to use another api; i.e. I don't want to diverge through other solutions; I just want a simple solution for that! `select()` is not that one and is messy